# Java - Sort a List of strings, determining the order depending on the contains of the string

Tags: java, string, list, sorting, javafx

*Example:*

Our list contains 5 names: **Kevin, Hans, Fritz, Han Solo, Peter**

And I now want to have all the names that contain "Han" at the top.

*So the sorted list would look like that:*

**Hans, Han Solo, Kevin, Fritz, Peter**

What I have tried so far:

Nothing because i have no clue, but i already googled and didn't find anything.

Deleting/adding items from/to the list is not an option becaue i am using the list in a `CheckListView` (ControlsFX component) where each item has a checked state which would get lost.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In java 8 you can create [`Comparator`s](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) based on a function applied to the element. Also there are methods to reverse the order produced by a comparator and chain comparators.

This allows a relatively simple creation of a comparator using the existence of a substring as primary sort criterion and the `String` sorting as secondary criterion. Note that depending on your requirements the second part (`.thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder())`) may not be necessary:

```
final String part = "Han";

Comparator<String> comparator = Comparator.<String, Boolean>comparing(s -> s.contains(part)).reversed()
        .thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder());
```

The result of sorting your items with this `Comparator` is

```
Han Solo, Hans, Fritz, Kevin, Peter
```

Comment: @sirmordred Why do you think the post starts with *"In java 8"*? Neither lambda expressions nor the convenience methods are available in java 7...

Comment: i know that the lambdas are only for java 8, i mean can the code above backported into java 7? with ifdef logic maybe?

Comment: ok i just changed the logic of the code posted below, return a.compareTo(b) instead of return 0

Comment: with that way, it will sort non-matching items in alphabetically order

Answer (score 3):

just use `Comparator` and define your own compare method with your conditions:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> names = Arrays.asList("Kevin,Hans,Fritz,Han Solo,Peter".split(","));

    Collections.sort(names, new Comparator<String>() {
        final String PREFIX = "Han";
        @Override
        public int compare(String a, String b) {
            if (a.contains(PREFIX) && b.contains(PREFIX)) return a.compareTo(b);
            if (a.contains(PREFIX) && !b.contains(PREFIX)) return -1;
            if (!a.contains(PREFIX) && b.contains(PREFIX)) return 1;
            return 0;
        }
    });

    for (String n : names) {
        System.out.println(n);
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT** (IMHO `Han Solo` must be prior to `Hans` because `space` is prior to `s` but you can easily modify my proposed conditions)

```
Han Solo
Hans
Kevin
Fritz
Peter
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to use a `Comparator<String>`.

When comparing two `Strings` lets call them `name1` and `name2`, if `name1` contains `"Han"` then you return `-1` indicating that `name1` should come first. If `name2` contains `"Han"` then you return `1` indicating that `name2` should come first. Otherwise neither String contains `"Han"` so you return `0` which indicates that they should not be swapped. **Note:** this does not alphabetically sort the Strings that contain `"Han"` as you did not specify this in your requirements.

In Java 8 this is simple:

```
List<String> names = Arrays.asList("Kevin", "Hans", "Fritz", "Han Solo", "Peter");

names.sort((name1, name2) ->
   name1.contains("Han") ? -1 :
   name2.contains("Han") ? 1  :
   0
);

System.out.println(names);
```

Output:

```
[Han Solo, Hans, Kevin, Fritz, Peter]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) to specify how the sorting should work.

This solution really **just moves elements containing "Han" to the front of the list - while keeping the original order between these elements** (as it was defined in the desired output) - and it **does not sort elements not containing "Han"** as the question states: "And I now want to have all the names that contain "Han" at the top."

```
List<String> names = Arrays.asList("Kevin", "Hans", "Fritz", "Han Solo", "Peter"));

names.sort(getMoveToFrontComparator("Han"));

System.out.println(names);

...

private Comparator<String> getMoveToFrontComparator(String part) {
    return new Comparator<String>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            boolean containsFirst = o1.contains(part);
            boolean containsSecond = o2.contains(part);

            // Match vs No-Match: Match has the priority
            if(containsFirst && !containsSecond)
                return -1;
            if(!containsFirst && containsSecond)
                return 1;

            // Match vs Match or No-Match vs No-Match: no sorting is needed
            return 0;
        }
    };
}
```

*The output is:*

```
[Hans, Han Solo, Kevin, Fritz, Peter]
```

**Note:** If you want to sort the "matching vs matching" and the "non-matching vs non-matching" case, you can replace `return 0;` with `return o1.compareTo(o2);`.

Comment: I did not want to sort strings not containing "Han". The OP states to move elements containing "Han" to the top. For me, it just means to move these elements to the top, don't touch other elements. And the order between "Han"s are defined by the desired output: Hans first then Han Solo - which means for me to keep the original order among "Han"s. That was the best I could figure out from this incomplete specification.

Comment: actually... I'm looking to my answer and it does same for not matching Strings... except mine compares if both contains han....  you beat me `:P`